# PureScript - Replace `launchAff_` with `launchAff`

Tags: purescript

Consider the following working code example, that uses `launchAff_` to copy a JSON file:

```
module Main where

import Prelude 
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Aff (Aff, launchAff_)
import Node.Encoding (Encoding(..))
import Node.FS.Aff (readTextFile, writeTextFile)
import Node.Path (FilePath)

duplicateCustomerData :: FilePath -> FilePath -> Aff Unit

duplicateCustomerData filePath1 filePath2 = do
  customer_data <- readTextFile UTF8 filePath1
  writeTextFile UTF8 filePath2 customer_data

main :: Effect Unit
main = launchAff_ do
  duplicateCustomerData "database/customer-1.json" "database/customer-2.json"
```

However, if the main function is changed to use `launchAff` (without the underscore) like so

```
main :: Effect Unit
main = launchAff do
  duplicateCustomerData "database/customer-1.json" "database/customer-2.json"
```

The following error is thrown:

```
  Could not match type
  
    Fiber Unit
  
  with type
        
    Unit
```

Thus,

1. What is a `fiber unit`?
2. What is the use case for this `fiber unit`? Is it meant to be discarded? What does it represent?
3. Why are there two launchAff functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Fiber`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/7.0.0/docs/Effect.Aff#t:Fiber) represents a *running* async computation.

The difference between `Fiber` and `Aff` is the "*running*" part. `Aff` is not an async computation that is running, but rather a way to start an async computation. It's not started until you bind it in a larger computation. And conversely, you can start the same `Aff` multiple times.

`Fiber`, on the other hand, is an async computation that has already been started, it's already in progress. You can kill it via [`killFiber`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/7.0.0/docs/Effect.Aff#v:killFiber) or you can wait for it to complete via [`joinFiber`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/7.0.0/docs/Effect.Aff#v:joinFiber), and some other things. See [the docs](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/7.0.0/docs/Effect.Aff).

And now that we know that (1) `Aff` is a way to start an async computation, and (2) `Fiber` is an already-running async computation, it should become obvious that a `Fiber` would be the *result* of starting an `Aff`. Which is exactly what you observe: `launchAff` takes an `Aff` and returns a `Fiber`.

But sometimes (in my own experience - most times) we don't actually need the resulting `Fiber`. There is nothing we're going to do with it. For those cases, there is a convenience shortcut - `launchAff_`. It does the same thing as `launchAff`, but throws away the resulting `Fiber`. See it for yourself [in the source code](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-aff/blob/2d44d9f9d0d6a416a4103fba2fb39e5160f80e36/src/Effect/Aff.purs#L229-L230).

Adding an underscore at the end to mean "*returns unit*" is a common pattern. For example, there are [`for`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/6.0.0/docs/Data.Traversable#v:for) and [`for_`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/6.0.0/docs/Data.Traversable#v:for_), there are [`traverse`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/6.0.0/docs/Data.Traversable#v:traverse) and [`traverse_`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/6.0.0/docs/Data.Traversable#v:traverse_), there are [`runAff`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/7.0.0/docs/Effect.Aff#v:runAff) and [`runAff_`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/7.0.0/docs/Effect.Aff#v:runAff_).